# Getting the value in a range which gives the maximum of a bounded function in z3py

Tags: python, z3, z3py

I have to get the value (in a range of them) that gives the maximum of a function, using z3py.
For example: I have a function (`foo(x,y) = 2*x + 1 + y`), and I want to find the value of `[x,y]` (using the constraint `lo <= foo(x,y) <= hi`) such that `foo(x,y)` is maximum.
In other words I have to solve a maximum problem within a range, is that possible?

I have wrote this simple script in python:

```
    s = Solver()
    # hi is given by the user
    # expr is foo(x)
    s.add(expr <= hi)
    s.add(expr >= lo)
    s.add(X >= 0)
    s.add(Y >= 0)

    if  s.check() == sat:
        print('_upper_bound: got model %s' % s.model())
```

If I use only a variable (e.g., `foo(x) = 2*x + 1`), the given model is correct and the value of `foo(x)` is the highest. If I use more than one variable (e.g., `foo(x,y) = 2*x+y`) the found result is the minimum.

All the points in the range are in the domain of the function.

EDIT: Apparently, if I remove the two constraints about X and Y, I get the maximum value.

Answer (score 2):

using `scipy`, you can `minimize` (you maximize -f if you minimize f)

```
scipy.optimize.minimize(fun, x0, args=(), method='BFGS', jac=None, 
    hess=None, hessp=None, bounds=None, constraints=(), tol=None, 
    callback=None, options=None)
```

as you see, you have a `bounds` parameter,

> bounds : sequence, optional Bounds for variables (only for L-BFGS-B,
>   TNC, COBYLA and SLSQP). (min, max) pairs for each element in x,
>   defining the bounds on that parameter. Use None for one of min or max
>   when there is no bound in that direction.

More detail on the optimization routines [to be found here.](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize)

Comment: Your solution is really good, but unfortunately I have just discovered that I have to work with z3py, since I have to deal with BitVectors.